# how to save an ID if the you leave the name empty?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm Working in this program for two days and i can not find out where I'm doing Wrong.If you could help me I really appreciate it .The Problem is when I enter 11111 for my the curator ID and leave the name Box Empty,it is not suppose to saved the curator ID  .After if I put something in the box and i enter 11111 for the Curator ID  it says "ID already exist please try again".

```
private void SaveCuratorBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    curator Curator = new curator();
    try
    {
        Curator.ID = CuratorIDbox.Text;
        bool sameid = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < curatorlist.Count; i++)
        {
            if (curatorlist[i].ID == Curator.ID)
            {
                sameid = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (sameid)
            MessageBox.Show("ID already exist please try again !");
        else
        {
            curatorlist.add(Curator);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
    }
    try
    {
        bool checkingname = false;
        Curator.NAME = CuratorNamebox.Text;
        checkingname = true;
        if (checkingname)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Curator Saved");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: you're adding the item to the list prior to ever checking that the name is not empty

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more bro?

Comment: if a curator is invalid (e.g. no name was provided) then it should never be added to the list. your first for loop checks for the existence of the curator's ID, if it isn't found, then it adds it.  It should be, if it isn't found ***and*** it has a name, then it should be added.

Comment: Just as a side note, why do people downvote beginner questions? This isn't a "how do I do this" type of question without researching anything. OP provided code that they've written and a problem they're having, it may be simple once you know the answer but we all started somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (sameid)
{
    MessageBox.Show("ID already exist please try again !");
}
else
{
    curatorlist.add(Curator);
}
```

This code block is doing the following:

- If the ID already exists, show an error (good!)
- If the ID doesn't exist, **add the whole Curator to `curatorlist`.**

What you need is another step of validation in your code to make sure that box the `name` textbox and the `ID` textbox contain information. You could achieve this like so (replace the names of course):

```
else 
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(NameTextbox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(IdTextbox.Text) 
{
    MessageBox.Show("Uh oh!")
} else {
    curatorlist.add(Curator);
}
```

Here you're checking if the textboxes are empty before even thinking about adding the Curator to `curatorlist`. If you need to make other checks (such as no numbers `[1,2,3,4]` in your `NameTextbox`), there are multiple ways of doing so.

Comment: Glad it guided you.

Answer (score 1):

You say that "when I enter 11111 for my the curator ID and leave the name Box Empty,it is not suppose to saved the curator ID"; but there is nothing in the sample code that you have provided which prevents this. That might be what you want; but you haven't coded it that way: the "curatorlist.add(Curator);" will add the curator to the collection regardless of what is in the Name box.

P.S. consider using a Dictionary, as the lookup will be faster.